# Replace fist character in filename

Tags: regex, powershell

I am reading file names and if the file does not start with an `N` I need to replace that letter with the letter `N`.

```psh
foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem $Path) {
  Write-host "working on $item"
  if ($item -match "^(N\d{3})") {
    # This file will already process correctly
  } elseif ($item -match "^(\d{3})") {
    $FilePath = $Path + $item
    Write-Host $FilePath

    #Rename this file so it will process correctly
    Rename-Item $FilePath N$item -Force
    Write-Host "Renaming: "$item "to N$item"
  } elseif ($item -match "^[a-zA-Z](\d{3})") {
    #replace first character with "N"
    # How do I replace the first letter with an "N"?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're thinking too complicated. This should suffice:

```
Get-ChildItem $Path | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -creplace '^[^N]','N' }
```

or this, if you don't want those files "renamed" that already start with an uppercase `N`:

```
Get-ChildItem $Path |
  Where-Object { $_.Name -cmatch '^[^N]' } |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -creplace '^[^N]','N' }
```